# Problems with pointers when building a Pascal compiler in C

Tags: compiler-construction, pascal, lexical

I'm facing some problems on the lexical analysis of my compiler
I had declared the following pointer

```
char *words[29]={
        "program",
        "label",
        "integer",
        "word",
        "char",
        "byte",
        "shortint",
        "logint",
        "real",
        "single",
        "double",
        "string",
        "boolean",
        "var",
        "procedure",
        "function",
        "begin",
        "end",
        "if",
        "then",
        "else",
        "or",
        "and",
        "div",
        "not",
        "do",
        "while",
        "mod"
};
char message[30];
```

and then I tried to use it in a function

```
for (handle = 0; (&words[handle] != NULL); handle++)
{
    message = &words[handle];
    if (!strcmp(token, message))
        message = 'words';
}
```

But I'm receiving the following errors when trying to execute:

> ```
> regarding (line message =
> &words[handle];) : warning C4047: '='
> : 'char [30]' differs in levels of
> indirection from 'char ** '
>
> regarding (line message =
> &words[handle];) : error C2106: '=' :
> left operand must be l-value
>
> regarding (line message='words';) :
> error C2015: too many characters in
> constant
>
> regarding (line message='words';) :
> error C2106: '=' : left operand must
> be l-value
> ```

can't I work with pointers that way?
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Three things:

1. The ampersands (`&`) are extraneous. The type of `words[handle]` is `char *`, i.e. a string, so right there you have what you need. You don't need to take the address of that `char *`.
2. You cannot directly assign to `message` with `=` as it is an array. C is not a very fancy language. You can either change `message` to `char *message`, so it is a pointer rather than an array; or you can use the `strcpy(dst, src)` function to copy to it, like so: `strcpy(message, "words")`.
3. Your `for` loop looks for a `NULL` pointer in the `words` array so it knows when to stop--but you don't have `NULL` in the array! You need to add `NULL` to the end. As written there are only regular strings so the loop will never find the null pointer it is looking for and will go charging off into uncharted zones of memory.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 3):

You have a number of errors there:

- instead of &words[handle], use
  words[handle]
- what are you trying to do by message = 'words'? There are at least 3 errors here: the string uses double quotes, not single quotes; message is a constant, you can't change it; to copy strings, you need to use strcpy(), not just = operator
- strcmp() returns 0, if the strings are equal; you need to reverse your logic
- you forgot to include NULL at the end of your array

Answer (score 2):

You have a number of problems with your code.  First of all, you should declare your array of keywords as `const char *words[]`.  It's bad practice to declare string constants as `char *`, without the `const`; it's only allowed so that legacy code still compiles.

You shouldn't specify the array size of 29 in the declaration, since it's fragile.  You should just use empty brackets and let the compiler figure out the array size.  You can get the size of the array by doing `sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0])`, which will still be correct even if you add or delete elements from `words`.

Next, your `for` loop is never going to terminate (although it will almost assuredly segfault at some point).  Taking the address of a value will never yield the null pointer, so `&words[handle] != NULL` will always be true.  The proper way to iterate through the loop is to just count the number of entries:

```
for(handle = 0; handle < sizeof(words)/sizeof(words[0]); handle++)
```

`message` is declared as an array of characters.  Arrays aren't assignable, i.e. they are not lvalues.  If you want to assign to an array, you have to explicitly copy data into it with something such as `strcpy()` (not recommended except in select cases, due to potential buffer overflows), `strncpy()`, `memcpy()`, or `strncpy_s()` (available only on Windows).

In this case, though, you don't want an array at all -- you just want to assign a pointer.  Declare `message` as a `const char *` instead.  With `message` declared properly, you would do:

```
const char *message;
...
message = words[handle];
if(!strcmp(token, message))
    message = "words";
```

In the final statement there, you should use double quotes around `words` to make it a string constant.  Single quotes are for single character constants (e.g. `'A'`).  Although they technically can contain more than one character, the endianness of the resulting integer constant is implementation-defined, and they're not what you want in this case.

I'm also not quite sure what you're trying to do with the `message = "words";` line.  If you're trying to do some clever trick with the `words` variable, stop right now, it's not going to work.  C doesn't have any sort of reflection.